# Python: convert unicode string to corresponding Unicode character

Tags: python, unicode

How do I convert a unicode string '05d1' to corresponding Unicode character '\u05d1' in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert string to codepoint (integer) first, and then it's just [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr):

```
>>> chr(int("05d1", 16))
'ב'
```