# Python: convert unicode character to corresponding Unicode string

Tags: python, unicode

How do I convert a unicode character 'ב' to its corresponding Unicode character string '\u05d1' in Python?

I asked the opposite question a few days ago:
[Python: convert unicode string to corresponding Unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67697058/python-convert-unicode-string-to-corresponding-unicode-character/67697067#67697067)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like,

```
>>> x
'ב'
>>> x.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace').decode('utf-8')
'\\u05d1'
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes):

> The errors parameter is the same as the parameter of the decode()
> method but supports a few more possible handlers. As well as 'strict',
> 'ignore', and 'replace' (which in this case inserts a question mark
> instead of the unencodable character), there is also
> 'xmlcharrefreplace' (inserts an XML character reference),
> `backslashreplace` (inserts a \uNNNN escape sequence) and namereplace
> (inserts a \N{...} escape sequence).

Comment: It worked, will convert from `rómulonaznazir125` to  `r\xf3mulonaznazir125`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works

```
>>> hex(ord('ב'))
'0x5d1'
```

Comment: You showed how to return charcode of this symbol in hex representation but forgot to add how to achieve desired format.

Answer (score 1):

[Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

> `unicode_escape` - Encoding suitable as the contents of a Unicode
> literal in ASCII-encoded Python source code, except that quotes are
> not escaped.

```
'ב'.encode('unicode-escape').decode()         ### '\\u05d1'
print('ב'.encode('unicode-escape').decode())  ### \u05d1
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer my own answer which is clean and simple:

```
json.dumps(unicode_character)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should have `json.dumps(unicode_character)[1:-1]`.  And this will always give surrogate pairs, e.g.  will dump to "\\ud83d\\udca9" when I guess "\U0001f4a9" would be preferable.

Answer (score -1):

```
decoded_string = "ב"
encoded_string = decoded_string.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: You've just encoded *str* to *bytes*, question is quite more complex

Comment: This will give the bytes of the character encoded as UTF-8 (`b'\xd7\x91'`), not `'\u05d1'`.